# Changed .Net Framework from 4.5 to 3.5, the Settings file now throws a ConfigurationErrorException

Tags: .net, frameworks, settings

I created a Windows program using .Net Framework 4.5. I then realized that I wouldn't be able to deploy it to Windows XP machines, so I changed the framework to 3.5. I've fixed several problems, but I'm struggling with this one. I re-created my Settings file. Now I'm getting the error `An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/RallyCourseDesigner.Properties.Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` any time I reference an item in the Settings. It's not clear to me where to start. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: There is no version 3.5.0.0 for System.dll, it is 2.0.0.0.  You'd of course be wise to compare the changes you made with a little test project that you created correctly.

Comment: OK, I think I went around and around on this, but I changed that in app.config and it looks like it worked. If you'd like to post it as an "Answer", I'll check it off for you...thanks!